# Can't open .rpt file in VS2019?

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019, crystal-reports-viewer

Why I Can't open .rpt file in VS2019?

This is my old project. I copy this source code project from my old computer.
On my old computer I used VS2019 and Crystal Reports version Service Pack 27 (CRforVS13SP27_0-10010309). So on my new computer aready installed these too.

But why I can't open my report? The warning show this and can't open.
[image]

On my old computer it can open normally.

And then I try to run the program. The program run to open report and show error like this.
[image]

And my last attempt. I tried creat new crystal report name is "npt3.rpt". It can open and work normally.

I don't know what to do next. I really don't understand what's going on. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

The text below is the full error.

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException
  HResult=0x80131600
  Message=Load report failed.
  Source=CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
  StackTrace:
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTable dataTable)
   at LabelProduction.FormNp_Print.Setreport() in D:\CNRLabel\FormNp_Print.vb:line 29
   at LabelProduction.FormNp_Print.FormNp_Print_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\CNRLabel\FormNp_Print.vb:line 250
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
   at LabelProduction.FormNp_Keyprint.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\CNRLabel\FormNp_Keyprint.vb:line 171
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at LabelProduction.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83
Inner Exception 1:
COMException: Unable to load report.
```

Comment: In my company we have the same problem when using Crystal Reports with VS2019. In our case, it is related with Crystal Reports version: when we use the version that is compatible with VS2012, it can't be used in VS2019. Maybe it is not related but it may help.

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to SAP support for this issue to see what they recommend.